Reading data using LINQ ends in timeout
I am reading data using LINQ query which has millions of rows and ends with a timeout. And how we can optimize the query to increase its performance.
var details  = await (from m in context.student
                                       .Include(m => m.studentdetails)
                      where m.studentnumber == studentnumber
                            && m.location == location
                            && m.class == class                                 
                      select m).ToListAsync();



Create index [studentnumber]/[location]/[class]
Contex.student.Include can optimize better


Why are you reading in that much data?

Also, make sure that you have an index on studentdetails(studentid) (or (studentnumber) or whatever column supports the FK relationship) to support the .Include() lookups. Beyond that, capture the generated SQL, execute it manually using SSMS, and examine the execution plan. If you still need assistance, upload the plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and post the resulting link back here. Please also post your tables schemas, including indexes and constraints.

AsSplitQuery() may help. But also consider to do not load everything, but apply paging.

@MasaTseng, We have indexes for these columns

@user2432361 You can try to select ten of rows and check if there are any timeouts. If not, it might be too many row data. You can try to use pagination. Refer to Paolo Tedesco Answer.

Apart from making sure that your tables are properly indexed, if yoy need to fetch a lot of entries you could use pagination, i.e. read data from the database in chunks.
If you are using Entity Framework Core, you can check out the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/pagination
I cannot provide a meaningful example without knowing the structure of your data, but it would be something along these lines:
var lastStudentNumber = -1;
var students = await context.student
    .OrderBy(s => s.studentnumber)
    .Where(s => s.studentnumber > lastStudentNumber)
    .Take(100)
    .ToListAsync();


Paolo, could you please put some detail in your answer so that future readers do not need to rely on the link?

I had thought about it, but it was quite hard to come up with a meaningful example for the OP's code without knowing the table structure...
